# Show record with condition

Tags: odoo-8

Suppose that I have a diagram like this

`-----------          -----------
| outcome | n       n|  course |
|---------|----------|---------|
| id      |          | id      |
| courses |          | code    |
-----------          | outcomes|
                     -----------`

I have a view to display outcomes. But now I want to get outcomes by course, for eg, get all outcome of the IT course. I tried to create 4 view records and use domain to filter the outcomes by course code but it won't work because the many2many rel. Please help me on this case.

Comment: What's the name of the middle table?? Can you show your code to give you an example?

Comment: The middle table's automatically created by odoo when compiling so no code, the name should be outcome_course_rel, just like how odoo named many2many rel table.